# how to align text in different uputs

Tags: pstricks

As can be seen from the image, there are 2 labels (a,b) that have misaligned baselines. I know that the problem arises because the height of the content in both `uput`s is different (*b* is taller than *a*). So the question is *how can I simulate a box with the height of a b but the contents of an a*

[image: x axis labels are misaligned]

There is a trivial answer using `rput` or tinkering with `labelsep` but I'm interested in a solution with `uput`'s content

## MWE

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)%
\psline{->}(-2,0)(2,0)%
\psdot(-1,0)\uput[270](-1,0){$a$}%
\psdot(+1,0)\uput[270](+1,0){$b$}%
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `$\mathstrut a$` and `$\mathstrut b$`, but there can be better methods (I'm no expert with `pstricks`).

Comment: The problem was tangentially about **pstricks**. The content inside the `uput` is what I was looking for and `vphantom` does the trick. I'll have to take a look at `mathstrut` because I have no idea what it does. Perhaps the question could use some editing

Comment: `\mathstrut` is defined as `\vphantom(` so it has the height and depth of a simple math element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could insert a `vphantom{b}` in front of `a`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)%
\psline{->}(-2,0)(2,0)%
\psdot(-1,0)\uput[270](-1,0){$\vphantom{b}a$}%
\psdot(+1,0)\uput[270](+1,0){$b$}%
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Perfect, `phantom`s are a feature I soon forget exist

Answer (score 1):

another possible solution:

```
\psdots(-1,0)(1,0)
\rput[b](-1,-3ex){$a$}\rput[b](1,-3ex){$b$}
```

Comment: I already knew that `rput` would be enough. What I don't know is the `-3ex` length. Three heights of _x_ under?